# Disable DatePicker tab stop

Tags: xaml, datepicker, tabstop

I am using the `DatePicker` control in the original WPF toolkit.

I am trying to remove the `DatePicker` from the tab order.
Setting properties like `IsTabStop` or `TabIndex` or `KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop` don't really work. Setting `TabIndex` to -1 for example removes it from the tab order until I reach the end of the tab order on my form and it cycles back to the beginning (which is the behavior I want). Once it has cycled the `DatePicker` is back in the tab order.

The problem seems to be that `DatePicker` encapsulates a `TextBox` which is the actual tab stop.

How can I set the `IsTabStop` property of `DatePicker`'s `TextBox` in XAML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Helped me a lot.  Here's how to do it in code behind:  KeyboardNavigation.SetTabNavigation(dateTimePicker, KeyboardNavigationMode.None);